# Turn any div into a popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, popover

The popover libraries I looked at generates arrows, ships own CSS and refuse custom HTML.

Is there a way to "popoverify" an **arbitary** div? That is, position it under/next to an anchor element, and listen to escape key and clicks outside of itself (both events make the outermost popover close).

Comment: May be a duplicate question. Take a look at this other question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263303/show-a-div-as-a-modal-pop-up

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers . This is a separate component in bootstrap, only depends on their tooltip. You may use it with your own markup.

Comment: @Esa I'm not sure, but a google images search for "popover" made me hungry.

Comment: In modern days it is called modal. :-)