# How to get the changed percentage from a function into a alert

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to create an alert in which the percentage of the downloaded file is shown.

I can already display that inside a html div with the following lines of code:

javascript file:

```
statusDom = document.querySelector('#status');

ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                 perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
                statusDom.innerHTML = perc + "% loaded...";


            } else {
                if(statusDom.innerHTML == "") {
                    statusDom.innerHTML = "Loading";
                } else {
                    statusDom.innerHTML += ".";
                }
            }
        };
```

html file:

```
<div class="status" id="status"></div>
```

But i would like to have it inside an alert box which looks like this:

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    perc + "% loaded...",  // message
    null,         // callback
    'Title',            // title
    'Cancel'                  // buttonName
    );
```

So how can I replace the `status2Dom.innerHTML = perc + "% loaded...";` for changing the value dynamically inside the alert box in the javascript file, instead the div file in html. Is there an easy line of code for doing it?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263303/show-a-div-as-a-modal-pop-up

Comment: notification.alert text can't be updated

Comment: Oh ok, thank you guys :)